# Qt QGraphicsSvgItem renders too big (0.5 unit on each side)

Tags: qt, svg, bounding-box, qgraphicsscene

If I draw an SVG item at (0, 0) with 64x64, the actual displayed SVG item is from (-0.5, -0.5) with 65x65. I measured this by drawing the boundingbox behind the SVG item. And the SVG item is sticking out at all sides by a half unit on the QGraphicsScene.

Can I remove this effect? I have set the pen to NoPen.
I could scale it down, but that would be quite unprecise (since width and height need different scaling, which is hardly possible). How can I fix this issue?

[image]

As you can see, the brown boxes (SVG) stick out over the grey area (bounding box). The bounding box is confirmed with Inkscape.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution using transform:

```
QSvgRenderer *test = new QSvgRenderer(QLatin1String("test.svg"));

QGraphicsSvgItem *item = new QGraphicsSvgItem();
item->setSharedRenderer(test);
addItem(item);

// the following transformation is required if you want the SVG to be exactly on the spot and as big as it should be
item->setTransform(QTransform(test->viewBoxF().width() / (test->viewBoxF().width() + 1.0), 0.0, 0.0, test->viewBoxF().height() / (test->viewBoxF().height() + 1.0), 0.5, 0.5));
```